# Trying to load an entire table in c# using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to load a set of results from a table eg: `select * from userTable where userGroup = "XXX"`. So it can be moved into the same table in another database, clearly a database link would solve my problem but is not allowed in this case. There are 2 oracle db with the same `userTable`, im using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types` (ver. 19.5.0) to connect to the db (the connection works fine). My issue is, I'm not sure how to pull a large amount of rows into the c# application.

I read about using `oracleBulkCopy` but that is no longer supported and other examples using `dataTable` classes but they don't seem to be supported anymore either and like stated above database links are not able to be used unfortunately. i can pull single users record using this code listed but not sure how to just pull all records and then insert them into another db.
(i just did the writelines to see if the data was being pulled)

```
con.ConnectionString = conString;
con.Open();
OracleCommand pullRecord = con.CreateCommand();
pullRecord.CommandText = "select* FROM  usertable where last_name='Smith'";
OracleDataReader reader = pullRecord.ExecuteReader();
string[] result = { "", "", "", "", "", ""};

if (reader.HasRows)
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
      result[0] = (string)reader["first_name"];
      result[1] = (string)reader["middle_name"];
      result[2] = (string)reader["last_name"];
      result[3] = (string)reader["department"];
      result[4] = (string)reader["active"];
      result[5] = (string)reader["phonenumber"];

      Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
      Console.WriteLine(result[1]);
      Console.WriteLine(result[2]);
      Console.WriteLine(result[3]);
      Console.WriteLine(result[4]);
      Console.WriteLine(result[5]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("press enter to continue");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I see the results of the query but honestly im lost on how to take that data and insert it into a second db, any help is appreciated

Comment: Of course DataTable can be used. Where did you get the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you not use DB-Links? It would be a single command only.

Anyway, this code will copy the data one by one:

```
  using ( var con = new OracleConnection(conString) ) {
     con.Open();
     var pullCmd = new OracleCommand("select * FROM usertable where last_name = :lastName", con);
     pullCmd.Parameters.Add("lastName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "Smith";

     var dt = new DataTable();
     var da = new OracleDataAdapter(pullCmd);
     da.Fill(dt);

     var pushCmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO new_table (first_name, middle_name, last_name, department) VALUES (:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :department)", con);
     pushCmd.Parameters.Add("first_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
     pushCmd.Parameters.Add("middle_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
     pushCmd.Parameters.Add("last_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
     pushCmd.Parameters.Add("department", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

     foreach ( DataRow row in dt.Rows ) {
        pushCmd.Parameters["first_name"].Value = row["first_name"];
        pushCmd.Parameters["middle_name"].Value = row["middle_name"];
        pushCmd.Parameters["last_name"].Value = row["last_name"];
        pushCmd.Parameters["department"].Value = row["department"];
        pushCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     con.Close();
  }
```

Comment: cant use db-links as the owner of the data has to sign off on using one and wont but is fine with using an external app to connect between two dbs, stupid i know

Comment: and when i try and use datatable for example exactly how you have it written it tells me the type or namespace could not be found. not sure what im missing though as these are my current usings.
  `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess;
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;`

Comment: `DataTable` is in namespace `System.Data` - Visual Studio offers this by right-hand mouse click -> Resolve

Comment: sorry had a hdd failure, going to try this now and get back to ya

Comment: now im hitting another issue i keep getting The following `ExecuteNonQuery` returns sql error: `ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist`
now i wonder is that due to me trying to connect to two separate db as the error hits on the `pushCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and not on the original select from the first db?

Comment: Most likely a typo, you did not define all parameters properly.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class to fetch the results

```
public void PersonDetails{
 private string FirstName{get; set;}
 private string LastName{get; set;}
 ...
 ....// write all required columns
}
```

Then after fetching the data

```
List<PersonDetails> personDet=new List<PersonDetails>();


if (reader.HasRows)
{
 while (reader.Read())
 {
  PersonDetails personDetail=new PersonDetails();
  personDetail.FirstName=(string)reader["first_name"];
  personDetail.LastName=(string)reader["middle_name"];
  ...
  ...//write for all columns 

  personDet.Add(personDetail)

 }
}
```

Now personDet contails all the selected rows

Now loop through personDet and write another insert query

Comment: How does it answer the question?